# How to get the current running class as an object?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a `JFrame` named `Server` which hosts a socket server with a `TextArea` to serve as a console. Each client which connects creates a new thread named `clientThread`.

My problem is : How can clientThread append a string to the TextArea in Server. I thought to pass the running class as a parameter but i have no idea how to do that. Any Ideas?

Client Thread:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread{
    Socket clientSocket;
    int ClientID = -1;
    boolean running = true;
    BufferedReader  in;
    PrintWriter out;
    Server console;

    public ClientThread(Socket s,int id,Server obj) throws IOException{
        clientSocket=s;
        ClientID=id;
        console=obj;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
    }
```

Server:

```
public class Server extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Server
     */
    public Server() {
        initComponents();
    }

    static public void writeToConsole(String s) {
        jTextArea1.append(s);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            ServerSocket servSocket = new ServerSocket(8008);
            writeToConsole("Server Started\n");
            int clientID = 1;
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = servSocket.accept();
                //Pass this class to the ClientThread As object??
                ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(clientSocket, clientID++, (theObjectOfThisClass))
                );
                    clientThread.start();
            }

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Server().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Edit: Fixed ClientThread Constructor

Comment: Are you looking for `this`?

Comment: @chrylis Ah yes this keyword works, but the class is non-static and the statement is within the main method. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused about how you are creating the threads. This occurs in an infinite loop, so even if you figure out how to send an instance of your `JFrame` to each thread, you will still never display the window.

Comment: So for some clarification, what is the purpose of these `ClientThread`s? How will they be used in the rest of the system you are building?

Comment: More importantly, why do you need infinitely many threads?

Comment: The Socket Server should create a new thread each time a client connects to it. Thus the server should be able to handle multiple clients at once. The infinitely loop is only to listen for incoming connections and allocate a thread to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `Server` as a parameter to the `ClientThread` constructor:

```
public ClientThread(Socket s,int id,ServerConsole obj, Server server)
```

Be careful when modifying the GUI from another thread, though. You will need to create a `Runnable` to run on the main UI thread with [`SwingUtilities`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html). You can use either `runAndWait()` or `runLater()`.

As you know, `main()` is static and therefore doesn't have a `this` reference. Instead, you are already creating a `Server` instance with `new Server()` later in `main()`. You need create this object sooner and store a reference to it so you can use it wherever you need to.

**Edit:**

What I have in mind is something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Server server = new Server();
    ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(clientSocket, clientID++, server);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        server.setVisible(true);
    }
});
    }
```

Note that since you only want one window you should only do `new Server()` once. You must do this to initialize the variable before using it otherwise the reference will be `null` which will cause more problems down the road.

Comment: Yes. That part I know. I want to know what to do here? ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(clientSocket, clientID++,(theObjectOfThisClass)));

Comment: @RenierSwart You need an reference to a `Server` object. The easiest way would be to create it before the loop and then reuse the same instance later to call `setVisible(true)`. However, I think you will encounter other problems since the `while` loop is infinite.

Comment: that might work, id give that a try and let you know.

Answer (score -2):

Okay I managed to fix the problem. For anybody with the same problem here is how to fix it:

Create a local variable to your current class:

```
static  Server svr;
```

Within the class constructor (pass the Server obj to itself)

```
public Server(Server server) {
        initComponents();
        svr=server;
    }
```

When the GUI invoke is called , send the local obj of the variable you created:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Server(svr).setVisible(true);
                }
            });
```

Thanks to Code Apprentice for the Idea.

Comment: What is the purpose of passing a Server to the Server constructor? Do you have multiple windows? Also why is the variable static?

Comment: The purpose of passing Server to Server constuctor is to allow the class thats currently running to be sent to ClientThread, This will not create multiple windows of Server and it is Static because Server is created within public static void main. It allows data which is sent from the client-side to be received by ClientThread and displayed on the Server's text area.

Comment: The Server class already has the this reference so you don't need to send another reference to the constructor.

Comment: Also static has nothing to do with where an o object created. It has more to do with how it is accessed.

Comment: Are you still creating your ClientThreads in main() or did you change that. If you didn't change it, passing a Server to the Server constructor is doubly unhelpful.